# Titanium Push Notification (Delay in Receiving Notification Android)

Tags: android, ios

I have implemented Appcelerator Titanium push notification in my application (Android and IOS) for 2 things:
1. Chat push notification
2. comment push notification

**Problem:** Right now I am testing in Android and I am facing problem while receiving Notification from appcelerator. Sometimes user is getting notification instant, but Sometimes he is getting notification with some delay (1 hour or sometimes 2 hour).

**For example:**  Suppose I have send a chat message to other user, then our local server will send this detail to Appcelerator, after that Sometimes other user is getting notification instant from appcelerator But Sometimes He (other user) is getting notification With some Delay (1 hour or Sometimes 2 hour).
Same with Comment Push notification.

Please can any one help me, how can I get Instant Notification from Appcelerator.

Thanks
Mohit Jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications are NOT guaranteed to arrive for a user and there is NO quality of service guarantee either (i.e. will be sent within 10 mins etc). Using notifications is great but can be unreliable. I'd say that only around 90% of them get through to those users who have agreed to receive them. There can be issues with users registering (accepting pushes) and those registrations getting through to Apple & Google properly. Apple's and Google's servers do not guarantee delivery and keep in mind that there can be significant delivery delays. And order of sending is not guaranteed either. Put all that together and the behaviour you are seeing is *pretty much standard* and you can't fix it.

Now, having said that, we have used websocket communication to enable real-time communication with devices while the app is running. Not sure if that helps you or not.

Comment: Thanks Ray for your answer, I will try to implement Websocket in my application to enable real-time communication.  Can you Help me how can I implement WebSocket for Chat and comment push notification in Titanium mobile application?

Comment: Are you sure Titanium Push notification can not receive Instant?

Comment: Can any one Help to Implement Instant push notification?